# Access database Winforms delete row given ID

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

In this code I retrieve the ID of the selected row and run a SQL command to delete it

```
// Ask for Confirmation
DialogResult response = MessageBox.Show("Tem a certeza?", "Apagar?",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
            MessageBoxIcon.Question,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
// ID of the row
int deleteid = (int)((DataRowView)sfDataGrid1.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[0];

// Tabela is the name of the table 
query = "DELETE FROM " + Tabela + " WHERE ID = " + deleteid;

oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);

if (response == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    try
    {
        oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // Says that data was deleted
        MessageBox.Show("Dados apagados com sucesso", "",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Show error message
        MessageBox.Show("Não foi possivel apagar os dados.\n " + ex.Message,
                        "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
}
else
{
    // Cancels the Action
    MessageBox.Show("Cancelado", "",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}

// Update the DataGridView
UpdateTable();
```

The code works, I can run it without any errors, but when I reset the program, the data I deleted is still there, even tho the feedback I get from the code is that the data was deleted successfully.

I've tried different ways of writing the command but the result is the same

The command string is:

```
"DELETE FROM tab_tasks WHERE ID = 2"
```

The command is executed without any error given by the program but it seems to not save the changes in the database.

As per request this is the UpdateTable():

```
 public void UpdateTable()
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = Caminho;
                connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        if (Tabela == "tab_tasks")
        {
            DataSet1TableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter dadapter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter();
            DataSet1.DataTable1DataTable dt = new DataSet1.DataTable1DataTable();
            dadapter.Fill(dt);
            sfDataGrid1.DataSource = null;
            sfDataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        Modify_Button.Enabled = false;
        Remove_Button.Enabled = false;
        sfDataGrid1.Update();
        connection.Close();
}
```

The condition is there because there's more than one table in the database. I had to do it this way, because the Data Shown in the DataGrid is different columns from different tables that have a common field (SubTasksId from tab_tasks is the same as ID from tab_subtasks)

Comment: You probably have a database file that is copied to the build output directory each time the application is compiled. Change its Build Action to `Copy if newer` -- If your setup is different, then specify what that is (how the database file is referenced in the Project).

Comment: the default location of the database file is: VisualStudio\AccessProject\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\
It's refered in the project with an encrypted connection string

Comment: That's not relevant. Do you have a reference to the database file in the Project? Or did you copy to or create the database file directly in the output directory? I.e., how did it end up there? E.g., you apparently are using a DataGridView. What fills it? Did you use VS tools to generate the bindings? -- What value does `ExecuteNonQuery()` return? -- (unrelated) Since you have a DataTable there, why don't you use a DataAdapter to perform these updates, so the DataGridView is also updated automatically when something in the datasource changes?

Comment: as per @Jimi see the [first image](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53248.visual-studio-copying-files-to-debug-or-release-folder.aspx), did you do this?

Comment: No, I didnt do that, I created the Database there

Comment: Check what number is being returns int rowsChanged = oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  Is ID a string or a number?  You probably want to use a parameter so it gets intepreted correctly.  Also check the conneciton string that you are changing the correct file.

Comment: Move the database to the project root folder, include it in the project. Set copy to output directory to copy if newer. Delete the database in the current location. Rebuild, run and check results. Also, inspect the connection string, make sure it is pointing to the app folder.

Comment: By moving the database to the project folder you can reset to the database original state if needed.

Comment: @KarenPayne moving the database to project root folder and changing the connection string worked, I also set it to copy if newer as Jimi said
Thanks everyone for the help provided

Comment: Note that if the database in contained in the application's startup path, if the User installs the app in `Program Files`, you may not have write access rights there. In WinForms, you usually move the database to `Application.CommonAppDataPath` or `Application.UserAppDataPath` (see what those are), the Connection string contains the `|DataDirectory|` substitution string, which is updated on first run calling `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "[New Directory Path]");`, so your Connection objects can always find the database. You should do this in any case, from the beginning.

Comment: @Jimi for first use on a new devide / when the application is moved, it asks the user for a new connection string and stores it in a txt file (encrypted text) so that there's no security risk and also the connection string can be changed any time in a easy way. I dont know if that will be a problem but i'll look into it later, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what use that can have with an Access database. When you open a connection, the connection string is visible, plain sight, in the memory space of your app. Also, if you *protect* the database with a password, someone could just open the database with an Hex Viewer and, well...

Comment: Anyway, this is not actually related to what I've describe before.